# $X_n$ is a sequence and uniformly distributed on $(-n,n)$. Does it converge in $L^p$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

If $X_n$ is a sequence and uniformly distributed on $(-n,n)$. Does it converge in $L^p$ and if it does then what would be the limit?

MY attempt consisted of finding the characteristic function which leads us to

the characteristic function  $$ \varphi_{X_n}(t) = \frac{\sin(tn)}{tn}$$ and so:

$$\varphi_{X_n}(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(tn)}{tn} &t \ne0\\ 1&t = 0\end{cases}.$$

and then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi(t)=\begin{cases}0 &t \ne0\\ 1&t = 0\end{cases}.$$

Now, I can see that when $t = 0$ for  $t \in \mathbb{R}  $, the limiting characteristic function $\varphi(t)$ is discontinuous. So the limit exists except for when $t=0$.
Hence we see that there is no convergence in distribution. From here can we conclude that it does not converge in $L^p$?

Is there any other way to prove this.
Thanks

Comment: Just to quickly comment on your last question. If the $X_n$ were $L^p$-convergent, then they would converge in distribution as well. Since they don't converge in distribution, they cannot converge in $L^p$. Note that an easier way of proving this is just observing that sequence $X_n$ isn't tight. That is, it's not true that $\forall \varepsilon>0\;\exists K>0:\: \mathbb{P}(|X_n|>K)\leq \varepsilon\; \forall n$. Indeed, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>K)=1$ for every $K$.

Answer (score 3):

$$E|X_n|^{p}=\frac 1 {2n}\int_{-n}^{n} |t|^{p}dt$$ $$ \geq \frac 1 {2n}\int_{n/2}^{n} |t|^{p}dt$$ $$ \geq \frac  1 {2n} {\frac n 2} |\frac  n 2|^{p} \to \infty$$ as $n \to \infty.$ Hence $(X_n)$ is not even bounded in $L^{p}$ for any $p >0$.